# Is the decay of nuclei also depending on the 'age' of nuclei or whether they are created or not?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

Usually the decay is said to be randomly but the average period of decay of certain atoms are stable. So if you randomly take a bunch of the same atoms the average time before the decay will fe be 5 days.

But imagine that you could create a bunch of atoms at the same time by decaying uranium atoms. Imagine that you succeeded in creating at the same time a buch of polonium atoms. So they all have the same age. Is the time that those polonium atoms decays in lead also has the same variety of decay with a certain average time or are all polonium atoms decaying more or less at the same time?

Perhaps uranium is not a good example, but it is about the principle question.

To make a distinction of other questions: when atoms are created is there a difference is spreading decay time among those atoms or is the spread of decay time the same, although of course the average time would stay the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Radioactive decay - What mechanism decides when an unstable nucleus decays?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/134828/)

Comment: It wouldn't make any difference. The nuclei don't come with an internal clock but they come with a decay probability. The probability that they will decay in any given time interval is constant.

Comment: of course the probabilty can stay the same but can the spread of the probability be different. So lets say usually it is between 20 and 60 days an atom decays but can it be in an experiment I mentioned be between 30 an 50 days?